# HTML text positioning in label

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

HTML:

```
<div>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    Promote
</label>
<label>
    <input type="text" maxLength="3" /> 
    Points needed
</label>
    <small>You need at least 5 points to promote</small>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.promote_comment {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding 3px;
}
```

This is a simple example from my project...I want to make the small text from the "promote_comment" label to be displayed on a new line inside this label. I have tried to do this using the display:block style or  tag, but those aren't working because it affects my layout. Is there other ways to do this?

https://jsfiddle.net/qgchhhp4/

Comment: You can force a new line with <br />

Comment: Why are you using a `label` to wrap other labels...that doesn't seem right.

Comment: I've mentioned that I tried this

Comment: You can't have more form inputs in one label - click on each one means click on label and focus to the first input.

Comment: Use div for the wrapper instead of a label and then make the `small` element `display:block` - https://jsfiddle.net/qgchhhp4/1/

Comment: You need to read up on how label works, it's not used for every time you want text on a page. Also the question needs to be clearer, it wasn't even clear that you'd tried `<br>` but you say this "affects your layout". How? What was the unwanted effect? It might be easier if you described what you want the end result to look like exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use div for the wrapper instead of a label and then make the `small` element `display:block` -

```css
.promote_comment {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
small {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    Promote
</label>
<label>
    <input type="text" maxLength="3" /> 
    Points needed
</label>
    <small>You need at least 5 points to promote</small>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly how I wanted it :D

Answer (score -1):

Here's one of the ways. Add this to your stylesheet. Although I'd recommend an id or class for the small text.

```
small {
    clear:both;
}
```